# ios How to enable video call using Linphone core

Tags: ios, linphone

I'm using Linphone core to make a callable app. Now I want to enable video call. Can anyone help me figure out all what I need to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use tokbox's SDK for server and client side to establish video calling. Have a [**look over here**](http://tokbox.com/opentok/tutorials/).

Comment: Thanks but my app has used linphone for audio call, I know Linphone supported for video call so I want to make use it so it costs a lot if I move to other opensource despite your very great recommend SDK.

Comment: This link may help you out http://www.linphone.org/eng/linphone/news/linphone-supports-video-calls-on-ios.html.............. d'ont forget vote

Answer (score 1):

Liblinphone has a C-level API. It's pretty OK documented but it's really hard to find. The very best I can find about placing/receiving/managing calls (both audio and video) is the page: [enter link description here](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone/group__call__control.html)

You need this function to enable video:

```
void linphone_call_params_enable_video (LinphoneCallParams *cp, bool_t enabled)
// cp - LinphoneCallParams object
// enabled - A boolean value telling whether to enable video or not.
```

Liblinphone is really tricky sometimes. There are several descriptions about video streaming inside the link I posted - check them too. There are not needed for my project - so the only one function I needed to enable video support is the one I posted - but maybe you'll need other functions too.

Hope it'll help someday.